# Remove minima from inner dimension in NumPy 2D array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

Hello I'm new to python and vectorization.

Say you have a 5x3 numpy array like this:

```
array([[ -1.262,  -4.034,   2.422],
       [ 13.849,  14.377,   4.951],
       [  3.203,  10.209,  -2.865],
       [  3.618,  -3.51 ,  -7.059],
       [ -0.098,  -5.012,   6.389]])
```

and you want to end up with a new 5x2 matrix with minima removed from each inner dimension like this:

```
array([[ -1.262,   2.422],
       [ 13.849,  14.377],
       [  3.203,  10.209],
       [  3.618,  -3.51 ],
       [ -0.098,   6.389]])
```

What is the best way to achieve that? I suppose it is with vectorization?

Thank you!

Comment: I always get confused with rows and columns: as printed in your question, you remove minima from the *rows*, not columns. But there probably is a way to argue it's column-wise. Instead, it's perhaps better phrased as having the minima removed from the second (inner) dimension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy: How to get rid of the minima along axis=1, given the indices - in an efficient way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368264/numpy-how-to-get-rid-of-the-minima-along-axis-1-given-the-indices-in-an-effi)

Comment: You are correct. I edited my question. I too get confused

Comment: Since your title-only edit was inconsistent with the question text (rows vs columns), I've removed both and replaced them with "inner dimension".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think there's a relatively straightforward function for this, but it may not be around in numpy; pandas could probably do this more easily.

With numpy, this is one way to do this:

```
In [56]: a = np.array([[ -1.262,  -4.034,   2.422],
       [ 13.849,  14.377,   4.951],
       [  3.203,  10.209,  -2.865],
       [  3.618,  -3.51 ,  -7.059],
       [ -0.098,  -5.012,   6.389]])
In [57]: m = np.argmin(a, axis=1)
In [58]: indices = np.ones(shape=a.shape, dtype=bool)
In [59]: indices[np.arange(5), m] = False    
In [60]: a[indices].reshape((-1, a.shape[1]-1))
Out[60]:
array([[ -1.262,   2.422],
       [ 13.849,  14.377],
       [  3.203,  10.209],
       [  3.618,  -3.51 ],
       [ -0.098,   6.389]])
```

The step with the boolean indices is to "invert" the indices returned from `np.argmin`, since the latter returns integer indices, not boolean indices.

Comment: I just noticed the duplicate of this question, after I entered this answer: the two answers there are similar to my answer here.

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful :-)